# Прикрепление драйвера модема в проекте Java EE

Tags: java, java-ee

Хочу получить список портов. В обычном Java Project работает прекрасно, а создаю Dinamic Web Project и выдает ошибку

> `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Serial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver`
> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Serial in java.library.path`
> `at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)`
> `at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)`
> `at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)`
> `at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java)`
> `at server.Server.main(Server.java:11)`

Собственно код простой, думаю, дело не в нём. Надо наверно куда-то впихнуть драйвер ещё? Подскажите, плиз.

```
package server;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import gnu.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //сканировать свободные модемы
        Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdn = ports.nextElement();
            int portType = portIdn.getPortType();
            String portName;
            switch (portType) {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_I2C:
                portName = "I2C";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                portName = "Parallel";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RAW:
                portName = "Raw";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RS485:
                portName = "RS485";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                portName = "Serial";
            default:
                portName = "hz_type";
            }
            System.out.println("Порт: "+portName+"\n"+portIdn.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так и выставьте java.library.path так, чтобы он указывал куда надо. А надо чтобы путь указывал на место, где лежат .so/.dll-файлы от RTXCOMM.

Чтобы установить java.library.path надо передать JVM'е опцию

```
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/directory/with/libs
```

Не знаю как там эклипс, но должны быть настройки запуска приложения. Если же речь идёт о приложении, работающем под appser'ом, то надо править опции запуска сервера.

Comment: а как это сделать в Ubuntu/eclipse?

Comment: Выдаёт список всевозможных команд...((

Comment: Не туда значит добавили это. Блин, ну прочтите этот список всевозможных команд. Там должно быть написано как пользовать ключём -D. Команда должна выглядеть как-то java -D.... -cp .... org.MainClass